# How to delete Availability Set in Azure using Azure-Python SDK

Tags: azure, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python, azure-availability-set

In Azure Cloud, I need to delete all the resources of the given instance using Azure-SDK for Python,
I'm able to delete resources like VM, PublicIP, NIC. I also need to delete the availability set of the instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete Azure Availability Set, you can use the package `azure.mgmt.compute`. It provides method `ComputeManagementClient.availability_sets.delete` to implement it. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2020_06_01.operations.availabilitysetsoperations?view=azure-python#delete-resource-group-name--availability-set-name--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet to delete an Availability Set using Azure SDK for Python:

```
from azure.common.client_factory import get_client_from_cli_profile
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient

compute_client = get_client_from_cli_profile(ComputeManagementClient)
    
def delete_vm_availability_set():
    compute_client.availability_sets.delete(<resource-group-name>, <availability-set-name>)

# Delete Availability Set
delete_vm_availability_set()
```

Equivalent Azure CLI command for this operation: [az vm availability-set delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/availability-set?view=azure-cli-latest#az_vm_availability_set_delete)

```
az vm availability-set delete -n MyAvailabilitySet -g MyResourceGroup
```

Other common management tasks with Microsoft Azure Virtual Machines using the Azure SDK for Python can be found in this sample: [Azure Virtual Machines Management Samples - Python](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/virtual-machines-python-manage)